# Cannot make MHDD bootable from pendrive using windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, bootable-media, bad-sectors

I downloaded an MHDD iso file and tried to make my USB bootable of the same using power ISO.But the mission failed.Why its not able to make the pen drive bootable?